# When item is checked on listview start new activity

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I Have an activity with a listview, the lest view has some check options in every line.

I would like to add to my code the possibility to start a activity when a check box is checked

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance!!

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_available_rides);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String messageTime = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String messageDep = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
    String messageArr = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
    String messageUser = intent.getStringExtra(DisplayMessageActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE6);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.textView26);
    textView1.setText(messageTime);
    TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView2.setText(messageDep);
    TextView textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textView3.setText(messageArr);
    TextView textView4 = findViewById(R.id.textView30);
    textView4.setText(messageUser);


    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference tripsRef = rootRef.child("Trips");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            List<String> listTime = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, listTime);
            ListView Time = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Listtime);
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String arrival = ds.child("Arrival").getValue(String.class);
                String departure = ds.child("Departure").getValue(String.class);
                String time = ds.child("Time").getValue(String.class);
                String trips = TextUtils.join("    |    ", new String[]{time, departure});
                String Trips = TextUtils.join(" ---> ", new String[]{trips, arrival});
                listTime.add(Trips);
                Time.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
    tripsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

after 
     Time.setAdapter(adapter);...
put this:

```
 Time.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            //you can start your activity here
        }
    });
```

If it's exactly checkboxes that you want in your list you will have to use a custom fit for your listView

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnItemClickListener method. You can define what should be done when each item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use to start a new activity an pass some content

```
Time.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("time", listTime.get(i));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Tairo! is intent.putExtra("time", listTime.get(i)); the command used to transfer the data that is in the specif row in the table view?

Comment: once you have the clicked position you can grab the object and move to another activity by inserting the object into an intent, this is just an example, the important thing is that you have the clicked position in adapter and you can get the object clicked with listTime.get(i);